# Extract directories from a list of paths

Tags: python, string, path

I have a list of paths to files, like this:

```
paths = [
    'A/B/b.py',
    'A/B/C/c1.py',
    'A/B/C/c2.py',
    'M/N/O/o1.py',
    'M/N/O/o2.py',
    'M/N/P/p1.py',
    'M/N/P/p2.py',
    'M/N/P/R/r2.py'
]
```

I want to transform that to a directory listing like this:

```
only_dirs = [
    'A',
    'A/B',
    'A/B/C',
    'M',
    'M/N',
    'M/N/O',
    'M/N/P',
    'M/N/P/R',
]
```

Those paths don't exist on the disk, they're just strings collected from DB, and I want to get a listing of directories in order to filter files according to any dir in the paths. What is the cleanest way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = set()
for items in paths:
    splitted = items.split("/")[:-1]
    for idx in xrange(1, len(splitted) + 1):
        result.add("/".join(splitted[:idx]))

only_dirs = sorted(result)
print only_dirs
```

**Output**

```
['A', 'A/B', 'A/B/C', 'M', 'M/N', 'M/N/O', 'M/N/P', 'M/N/P/R']
```

Comment: I'd use the `os.path.dirname()`, `os.path.split()` to have it cross-platform.

Comment: @LaurIvan Correct, but OP says `Those paths don't exist on the disk, they're just strings collected from DB` in the question :)

Comment: @thefourtheye, afaik these don't check for the physical existence of paths. Your solution is correct because using `os.path` calls on windows would probably generate wrong results (although it would be interesting to test)...

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED ANSWER**

As pointed out in a comment by thefourtheye, my first answer was incorrect.

Here is a new solution to the problem:

```
only_dirs = []

for path in paths:
    current = path[:path.rfind('/')]
    while len(current) > 0:
        if current not in only_dirs:
            only_dirs.append(current)
        current = current[:current.rfind('/')]

only_dirs.sort()
print only_dirs
```

Comment: This produces `['A/B', 'A/B/C', 'A/B/C', 'M/N/O', 'M/N/O', 'M/N/P', 'M/N/P', 'M/N/P/R']` and it is not what OP expected.